# What is the best method to clear logs?

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, log, crontab

I run with a dedicated Debian server and I wish like to know what is the best method to clear my logs in my database?

Currently, I use the Magento cron every 5 minutes. It's work fine and when I check on my database in my cron_schedule table, the cron works every 5 minutes.

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /path/to/magento/cron.sh
```

Now, I wish clear the following tables every five minutes :

```
dataflow_batch_export
dataflow_batch_import
log_customer
log_quote
log_summary
log_summary_type
log_url
log_url_info
log_visitor
log_visitor_info
log_visitor_online
report_viewed_product_index
report_compared_product_index
report_event
```

What is the best method for realize that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In simple way,you can do it.

**Create a php script at Magento application root dir where cron.php file is located.**

**the using mysql query truncate data from database table**

**add This php script at cronjob as per as your requirement**

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app("admin"); // run application as admin
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$query1 = "truncate table dataflow_batch_export";
$query2 = "truncate table dataflow_batch_import";
$query3 = "truncate table log_customer";
$query = "truncate table log_quote";
$query4 = "truncate table log_summary";
$query5 = "truncate table log_summary_type";
$query6 = "truncate table log_url";
$query7 = "truncate table log_url_info";
$query8 = "truncate table log_visitor";
$query9 = "truncate table log_visitor_info";
$query10 = "truncate table log_visitor_online";
$query11 = "truncate table report_viewed_product_index";
$query12 = "truncate table report_compared_product_index";
$query13 = "truncate table report_event";

$writeConnection->query($query1);
$writeConnection->query($query2);
$writeConnection->query($query3);
$writeConnection->query($query4);
$writeConnection->query($query5);
$writeConnection->query($query6);
$writeConnection->query($query7);
$writeConnection->query($query8);
$writeConnection->query($query9);
$writeConnection->query($query10);
$writeConnection->query($query11);
$writeConnection->query($query12);
$writeConnection->query($query13);
$writeConnection->query($query13);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is magento setting already provided for it

```
System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Log Cleaning
```

You can configure your store to automatically clean up these logs.